# Nuances of meaning between "Если бы", "Вот бы", and "Вот если бы"

Tags: словоупотребление

> **Если бы** и в жизни было так.
>
> **Вот бы** и в жизни было так.
>
> **Вот если бы** и в жизни было так.

In conversation, I tend to use whichever comes to mind first, but I'm wondering how they are nuanced.

Answer (score 3):

**Вот бы** = *хорошо бы* (expressing a desire lazily, without much hope):

> Вот бы сейчас пива холодного.

**Если бы** typically introduces an *unreal* condition (your example is an incomplete sentence):

> Если бы и в жизни было так, все люди были бы счастливы.

**Вот если бы**: the *вот* element introduces an *exceptional* condition for something to be true (the whole expression demonstrates eagerness to agree with an opponent about an unlikely situation).

> Вот если добавить в этот гамбургер черной икры, он станет вполне
>   съедобным.

Comment: his examples sound like reactions to some event or situation and as such are complete.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Ah, yes. We were talking about a TV drama series, then I said this.

Comment: "Вот бы" is a wishful expression that can also be about the past. "Вот бы нам тогда пива холодного!"

Answer (score 1):

*Если бы и в жизни было так.* - expresses observation on a condtion which in real life is usually not true (e.g. something happens in a movie, you know it's not possible in real life, hence this comment - If only this could happen in real life, etc....) - sounds more like an observation or comment with doubt.

*Вот бы и в жизни было так* - expresses the DESIRE that this could happen in real life, but the implication is again that in fact it's not likely to happen, it's just your wish or dream.

*Вот если бы и в жизни было так.* - basically the same as No.1, but Вот adds more doubt, or makes it sligthly more emphatic.